# Mongoose never connects to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB using Mongoose on an Amazon EC2 Linux server.

Here's my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log("Attempting antyhing to do with mongoose"); //shown

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'db connection error:')); //not shown
db.once('open',function(){
    console.log("Successful connection to db!"); //not shown
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/local',function(err){
    console.log("some kinda connection made"); //not shown
    if(err)
    {
        console.log("err: "+err);
    }
});
```

Frustratingly, I'm not getting any errors from mongoose whatsoever, but nothing seems to show up.

There seem to be a lot of questions about no callback with mongoose and mongo.

Here's a couple that I've looked at that I don't think are the problem for me:

- Listen for the callback quickly:
  [Mongoose Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360531/mongoose-connection) I
  moved my db.on('open'... call to before my connect call in case of a
  race condition.
- Is Mongo running?
  [Mongoose connect method fails on simple Node Server. Express, Mongoose, Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544815/mongoose-connect-method-fails-on-simple-node-server-express-mongoose-path)
  Yes, and on port 27017

Also for reference I'm following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

One thing I am doing that I'm worried about is I've split my code up into multiple files. So this mongoose connection code is being called from a app/models/host.js (or bear.js in tutorial) file. Let me know if posting the other files would be helpful.

Comment: I've had the same issue following the same tutorial. I'm running mongo locally on a mac, installed via homebrew. I can connect via CLI and execute commands. The app manages to form 5 connections (I can see them in the mongod terminal) but hangs indefinitely on any query. Still haven't found the problem :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also faced the same issue.

Check that the Mongoose version you are using supports the MongoDb server version

Check compatibility on this link: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html

Change the version of Mongoose in package.json file accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For what its worth, I've experienced the same, and turns out I was using the wrong MongoDB version on my Mac, coupled by a wrong version of the NodeJS Driver for MongoDB. For posterity, what's working for me now is:

NodeJS Driver for MongoDB: ^3.1.9
MacOS MongoDB version: 4.0.4.

Finally the db.open() event is triggered for me. I was running out of hair to pull out!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really solved the problem but I found a work-around... not using mongoose. Would still appreciate connecting to mongoose, especially as I was trying to follow a tutorial.

Here's my code that successfully connects to mongodb:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/host";

//Go Ahead and connect & sketchily initialize the db
var db;
var collection;
MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,database){
    if(err){
        console.log("Coudln't connect to mongo. Error"+err);
    } else{
        db = database;
        collection = db.collection('hosts');
        console.log("Connected to mongo, db good to go");
    }
});
```