# Browser waiting on localhost on POST request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post

I'm building a website, and i have a registration form where i need to submit a form via POST, and register a user in a mongoDB databse. The website works fine so far, but when i submit the registration form the browser just "waits for localhost" forever. I use EJS as my templating engine, although i don't think that matters.

register.ejs:

```
<% include partials/header %>
<%include partials/nav %>
<h1>REGISTER</h1>
<a href="/login">Login</a>

 <form  id="registerForm" action="/register" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Your password must be at least 8 characters long.</small>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require("passport"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    User = require("./models/user"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

//Set up MongoDB
var mongo = require("mongo");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/customerapp';
//MongoJS
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var db = mongojs("customerapp", ["users"]);
//Mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/customerapp");
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "wah wah wah",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


var index = require("./routes/index");
var about = require("./routes/about");
var login = require("./routes/login");
//var register = require("./routes/register");

app.all("index", index);
app.all("about", about);
app.all("login", login);
//app.all("register", register);

// AUTH Routes
//Register get request
app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});

//Handle post register req. at '/register'
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({
        username: req.body.username}),
        req.body.password,
        function(err, user) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.render("register");
            }
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                res.redirect("/secret")
            })
    });
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using three params instead of two, use it like this.

```
//Handle post register req. at '/register'
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
        }),
    function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("register");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
            res.redirect("/secret")
        })
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your versions of mongoDB and mongoose are compatible. You can find a compatibility chart [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html).

In addition to checking your MongoDB and mongoose versions, you should also check if it's actually connecting to the database by using a callback function when you connect to the server, like so:

```
//Connecting to database using mongoose.connect with a callback
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/customerapp", function(error) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("There was an error connecting to MongoDB.");
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  }
});
```

This callback may also work with `mongoose.createConnection` instead of `mongoose.connect`, but I haven't tried. If neither message prints to the console, then the app is not getting any response from the server, not even an error.

For some reason, as long as mongoDB is running at all, GET requests still seem to work even if the connection attempt hangs, but POST requests run into trouble.

Source: [Mongoose never connects to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428744/mongoose-never-connects-to-mongodb/43636977)