# Mongoose connect callback never called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having difficulties using mongoose. I have this small code which makes a connection to mongodb server.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db', function (err) {
    console.log("on connect callback called");
    if (err) throw err;
});
console.log("connect called");
```

Unfortunately on running this code, I get `connect called` in console but the `on connect callback called` is **never** called.

My mongodb console shows that it had got some connections when I run this code

```
2018-02-09T11:42:15.422+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-02-09T11:42:21.968+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56156 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-02-09T11:42:21.970+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56158 #2 (2 connections now open)
2018-02-09T11:42:21.971+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56160 #3 (3 connections now open)
2018-02-09T11:42:21.971+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56162 #4 (4 connections now open)
2018-02-09T11:42:21.971+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56164 #5 (5 connections now open)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for `mongoose.connect` is not a callback, it is an options object describing the `poolSize`, `autoIndex`, `user`, `pass` etc. To have something called once after the connection has happened, you should use the method `once` on `open`:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db', {poolSize: 20});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function() { console.log('Successfully connected');});
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'conn error:'));
```

The OP found the issue in the version compatibility. Once upgrading his `mongoose` version to `5.0.4`, it worked.

Comment: Okay. But I do not get `Successfully connected` when I run this

Comment: I have added a line to catch errors. Try running that and see if there are any errors.

Comment: also if you have any username and password, you should add them to options object: `{user: 'gaurav', pass: 'password'}`

Comment: Nothing prints on the console and mongodb shows the same logs as above

Comment: It is printing `Successfully connected` on my console. Is your mongodb server up and running okay. Were you able to open a mongodb connection from console using `mongo` client.

Comment: Yes. The mongodb server is running. I am able to use `mongo` client and create and query documents. but when i use mongoose, the server shows that it has received some connections, but nothing happens then. It looks like a compatibility issue between mongodb version `3.6.2` and mongoose version `3.6.2`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428744/mongoose-never-connects-to-mongodb?rq=1

Comment: Hmm, could be the case. Try the solution in one of the answers, testing the version compatibility.

Comment: Solved by upgrading mongoose to v5.0.4. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you write this in your answer, I will accept it.